How to customize "Internal Server Error" response in API Gateway?
I utilize API Gateway v2 configured with HTTP API. Additionally, I have a Lambda function configured to handle simple HTTP requests. Whenever an unexpected error occurs within a lambda, the following response is returned to the client (set by AWS).
{ 
  "message": "Internal Server Error" 
}

I would like to have control over how the internal server error appears. For instance, I would prefer it to look like this.
{ 
  "error_code": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
  "error_description": "My custom error description" 
}

How can I achieve this?
